# question about eBPF Kprobe on Android AOSP. How can I use "struct sk_buff"?

Tags: android, android-source, ebpf

Recently I learn about eBPF and found it really amazing, so I want to build some eBPF program on AOSP custom ROM.

Following Google's guide, I have succeeded in making tracepoint program and I can collect event such as tcp_retransmit_skb. And I would like to try to collect some icmp/udp events, it seems that I need to use kprobe to achieve my goal.

My idea is this, set up kprobe attach to 'ip_finish_output' and 'ip_local_deliver_finish', and parse data from sk_buff, so that I could collect infos about remote port、remote address etc.

However the problem is, compiler can not find <linux/skbuff.h>, so I copy the kernel header to my include folder, and setup my Android.bp file like this.

```
bpf {
    name: "tcp_diag.o",
    include_dirs: [
        "packages/modules/Connectivity/bpf_progs", //bpf_headers
        "vendor/magicdian-demo/packages/modules/NetworkDiagnostics/bpf_progs/include/msm-kernel/include", //kernel_headers
        "vendor/magicdian-demo/packages/modules/NetworkDiagnostics/bpf_progs/include/msm-kernel/arch/arm64/include", //kernel_headers
        "vendor/magicdian-demo/packages/modules/NetworkDiagnostics/bpf_progs/include/msm-kernel/arch/arm64/kvm/hyp/include", //kernel_headers
        "vendor/magicdian-demo/packages/modules/NetworkDiagnostics/bpf_progs/include/msm-kernel/tools/arch/arm64/include", //kernel_headers
        "vendor/magicdian-demo/packages/modules/NetworkDiagnostics/bpf_progs/include/msm-kernel/tools/perf/arch/arm64/include", //kernel_headers
    ],
    srcs: ["tcp_diag.c"],
    cflags: [
        "-Wno-unused-variable",
        "-Wall",
    ],
}
```

then I try build my program, so I run `./build.sh --qssi_only tcp_diag.o`, and the compiler output

```
vendor/magicdian-demo/packages/modules/NetworkDiagnostics/bpf_progs/include/msm-kernel/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic_ll_sc.h:93:46: note: expanded from macro 'ATOMIC_FETCH_OP'
        : "=&r" (result), "=&r" (val), "=&r" (tmp), "+q" (v->counter)   \
                                                    ^
vendor/magicdian-demo/packages/modules/NetworkDiagnostics/bpf_progs/include/msm-kernel/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic_ll_sc.h:112:1: error: invalid output constraint '+q' in asm
vendor/magicdian-demo/packages/modules/NetworkDiagnostics/bpf_progs/include/msm-kernel/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic_ll_sc.h:107:2: note: expanded from macro 'ATOMIC_OPS'
        ATOMIC_FETCH_OP (_relaxed,        ,  ,  ,         , __VA_ARGS__)\
        ^
vendor/magicdian-demo/packages/modules/NetworkDiagnostics/bpf_progs/include/msm-kernel/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic_ll_sc.h:93:46: note: expanded from macro 'ATOMIC_FETCH_OP'
        : "=&r" (result), "=&r" (val), "=&r" (tmp), "+q" (v->counter)   \
                                                    ^
vendor/magicdian-demo/packages/modules/NetworkDiagnostics/bpf_progs/include/msm-kernel/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic_ll_sc.h:112:1: error: invalid output constraint '+q' in asm
vendor/magicdian-demo/packages/modules/NetworkDiagnostics/bpf_progs/include/msm-kernel/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic_ll_sc.h:108:2: note: expanded from macro 'ATOMIC_OPS'
        ATOMIC_FETCH_OP (_acquire,        , a,  , "memory", __VA_ARGS__)\
        ^
vendor/magicdian-demo/packages/modules/NetworkDiagnostics/bpf_progs/include/msm-kernel/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic_ll_sc.h:93:46: note: expanded from macro 'ATOMIC_FETCH_OP'
        : "=&r" (result), "=&r" (val), "=&r" (tmp), "+q" (v->counter)   \
                                                    ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
4 warnings and 20 errors generated.
18:01:18 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (01:35 (mm:ss)) ####
```

tried googling, however not found related problem. I don't know how to solve this problem. Maybe I need to modify my Android.bp file?